# App Crashing when calling a Fragment from an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-activity

I'm developing an app where I have a fragment as my home page. I'm currently trying to call that fragment from an activity but unfortunately it is crashing. I had even implemented the FragmentTransaction and it still doesnt want to pick it up.

logcat

```
05-02 22:22:40.331 5927-5927/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.treycoco.calorietracker, PID: 5927
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method'    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransactio android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference at com.example.treycoco.calorietracker.CalorieDetails$1$1.onClick(CalorieDetails.java:79)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

update logcat

```
          example.treycoco.calorietracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.treycoco.calorietracker, PID: 19224
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0080 (com.example.treycoco.calorietracker:id/FragmentHolder) for fragment FragmentHome{d567f7e #0 id=0x7f0e0080}
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

caloriedetails.java

```
   public class CalorieDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TextView foodName, calories, dateTaken;
   private Button shareButton;
   private int foodId;
   private Button deleteButton;

   private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
   private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_details);

    foodName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsFoodName);
    calories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detscaloriesValue);
    dateTaken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsDateText);


    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);


    Food food = (Food) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userObj");

    foodName.setText(food.getFoodName());
    calories.setText(String.valueOf(food.getCalories()));
    dateTaken.setText(food.getRecordDate());


    foodId = food.getFoodId();
      foodName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      dateTaken.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    calories.setTextSize(34.9f);
    calories.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO: put delete functionality here
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new 
       android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(CalorieDetails.this);
            alert.setTitle("Delete?");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
            alert.setNegativeButton("No", null);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    DatabaseHandler dba = new 
        DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    dba.deleteFood(foodId);

                    Toast.makeText(CalorieDetails.this, "Food Item 
      Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome()
                    fragmentTransaction =  
                   getSupportedFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder, 
        fragmentHome);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();



                    CalorieDetails.this.finish();

                }
            });

            alert.show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

caloriedetails.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       tools:context=".CalorieDetails"
       android:background="@drawable/imgbackground2"
     style="@style/AppTheme"

      >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/weight"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"

    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detsFoodName"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:text="dkdad"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detsCaloriesTitle"
        android:text="Calories:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detscaloriesValue"
        android:text="200"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detsDateText"
        android:text="Consumed on..."
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:text="DELETE"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the fragmentManager and fragmentTransaction but not yet initialized.

```
FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
 fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder, fragmentHome);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Remove this line from onClick method,

```
CalorieDetails.this.finish();
```

Because you are going to add the fragment in activity so dont finish the activity.

Add this code in your caloriedetails.xml file

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/FragmentHolder"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Please do some google search before start implement.

Comment: I implemented the code above and I still get an error :/

Comment: Post your activity_calorie_details.xml file. I think you may not added the FrgamentHolder in layout file

Comment: I just updated Hopefully can see the problem this is my first time working with android studio

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: It worked Thanks A lot!
I'm sorry I thought I was doing it correctly. I need to remember to put an id on the xml thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your fragmentTransaction is null as you don't initialize it hence the exception.

Do this

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
```